How can i know if there would be an announce or a new in my currency with Pine Script tradingview?
I am currently developing a script in which i buy whenever RSI reaches a certain value, but i only want to start the operation if there will be no news planned in the next 4 hours, so how can i get that?
I've tried searching for some other people with the same doubt, but couldn't find anything. Also asked to chatgpt and there is no response.
I am hoping that, as chatGPT is outdated, there would be an actual function added in Pine Script v5 that searches for any news in the future, but i don't know the name such function could have.

You must create your own calendar, and save the data in your own Github repository. You can then query this data with request.seed()

This service has been suspended for new repositories: https://github.com/tradingview-pine-seeds/docs
